# IE8 lumps CSS styles together

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am debugging my app in IE8's developer mode and I'm running into some very strange behavior. IE8's dev mode usually displays every CSS style on a new line, but not in these cases... take three examples:

```
#1
.messages .read    
  background-color: rgb(234,234,234); HEIGHT: 1.5em
  padding-top: 0.3em

#2
a:link
  color : rgb(80,80,82); TEXT-DECORATION: none

#3
#messaging .body
  border-bottom: rgb(...) 1px solid
  filter : progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FDFDFD', endColorstr='#C2C2C2'); BORDER-LEFT: rgb(...) 1px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1.5em; MARGIN: 15px 0 25px; etc.
```

As you can see, these are three cases where IE seems to behave strangely, and especially for `#3`, I get some really strange artefacts, such as an ugly dark grey border around my gradient box.

Is there a known way of getting around this behavior?

### Update - gradient artefacts fixed

`#3` was fixed surprisingly easily, by adding `position:relative;` to that style. Apparently IE needs this in order to render its gradients properly.

I'm still interested in knowing why IE lumps some styles together on one line, and whether this quirk has any actual effect.

Comment: I've seen this sort of thing happen in IE's dev tools in cases where the stylesheet has some sort of syntax error.

Comment: Happens to me too but this is probably a glitch; I think it still renders the rules correctly... correctly according to its own standards.

Comment: There still might be syntax error in the CSS, IE might just coincidentally be getting it right. Run it throught a lint test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the samples you give there are at least some missing semi-colons. This may very well be the problem here.

As suggested in comments: try to validate your CSS. Here's the one from W3:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/